# validate a form before it get submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I have a form in my jsp page. I submit the form using `Ajax`. I do not use a `submit` type button, I use a `button` type button to call a `javascript` function which includes `ajax` . I call that javascript function on above mentioned button click. 
Now I need to validate my form. For that I use jquery form validation from [here.](http://www.javascript-coder.com/form-validation/jquery-form-validation-guide.phtml) They use a function like this to validate form.

```
$(function(){

                 $("#detailForm").validate({
                     rules:{
                         regdate:{
                             required:true
                         },
                         agreementNo:{
                             required:true
                         },
                         customerName:{
                             required:true
                         },
                         customerAddress:{
                             required:true
                         },
                         customerNic:{
                             required:true
                         },
                         telephoneNo:{
                             required:true
                         },
                         jobDescription:{
                             required:true
                         }

                     }
                 });

             });
```

Now I cannot figure out how do I validate the form before I submit it. Above function cannot be called in a way like this.

```
$("#btn1").on('click',function(){


                     $("#detailForm").validate({

                         rules:{
                             regdate:{
                                 required:true
                             },
                             agreementNo:{
                                 required:true
                             },
                             customerName:{
                                 required:true
                             },
                             customerAddress:{
                                 required:true
                             },
                             customerNic:{
                                 required:true
                             },
                             telephoneNo:{
                                 required:true
                             },
                             jobDescription:{
                                 required:true
                             }

                         }
                     });


             });
```

they call validate function on submit type button click.

So how can I do this. I need to validate the function and call the javascript which includes ajax on my button type button click.  help me in this case.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the rules as you are upon load. Then upon button click, you can use the `valid()` method to check the forms' state.

```
$("#btn1").on('click',function(){
    if ($("#detailForm").valid()) {
        // form is fine, send data as needed
    }
    else {
        // form was not valid. Messages should have been shown.
    }
});
```

Comment: can I use the first function I have mentioned inside the else part

Comment: sry for that comment. I solved my problem.thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the result of your `validate` like so:

```
$("#btn1").on('click',function(){
    var validator = $("#detailForm").validate({
     rules:{
         regdate:{
             required:true
         },
         agreementNo:{
             required:true
         },
         customerName:{
             required:true
         },
         customerAddress:{
             required:true
         },
         customerNic:{
             required:true
         },
         telephoneNo:{
             required:true
         },
         jobDescription:{
             required:true
         }
     }
    });

    if (validator.form())
    {
        //form is valid
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        //can also display error messages using validator.showErrors(errors)
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Why would you only set up the validation rules after the submit button is clicked? They should be set on load so that the user can see errors as they are inputting the values.